# Show that a sequence of MA(n) processes does not converge to zero

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, convergence, moving-average

I am trying to investigate whether a certain MA($n$) process does not necessarily converge to zero when $n \to \infty$. Consider $X_n=(X_{t;n})_{t =1}^\infty$ a MA($n$) process such that:
$$X_{t;n} = \sum_{j=0}^{n} \theta_{j;n} \varepsilon_{t-j;n}$$
satisfies the two following properties:

1. $\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim}\underset{1\leq j \leq n}{\max}  |\theta_{j;n}|=0$
2. For each $n$, we have that $(\varepsilon_{t;n})_{t\in \mathbb Z}$ is i.i.d. with $E[\varepsilon_{t;n}]=0$ and $E[\varepsilon_{t;n}^2]=1$

Intuitively, at first glance, this might look like $X_n$ converges to zero. For example, consider the following simulation in Julia when the innovations are Normal:

```
using Distributions
using Plots

# Size of my Time Series MA(n)
T=1000

# Order of the MA(n)
n = 10

# Property 1
max_n = 1/n
θₙ = rand(Uniform(-max_n, max_n), n)

# Normal distribution N(0,1)
dist = Normal()
# I need lags
εₙ = rand(dist,T+n)

# My X times series MA(n)
Xₙ = [0.0 for i = 1:T]
for t in 1:T
    τ = t + n
    Xₙ[t] = θₙ[1]*εₙ[τ]
    for j in 2:n
        Xₙ[t] = Xₙ[t] + θₙ[j]*εₙ[τ-j]
    end
end
plot(Xₙ, size = (950, 350), legend = false , title = "MA($n)")
```

[image]
For n = 800, we have
[image]

But I have the impression that for non-Gaussian innovations (maybe t-student), MA(n) doesn't necessarily converge to zero (satisfying properties 1 and 2 above). So, I would like to know if there is any way to show that for some innovation $(\varepsilon_{t;n})_{t\in \mathbb Z}$ and for some $\epsilon>0$, I have

$$|X_{t;n}|> \epsilon, \quad \forall \, t \in \mathbb Z , \forall n \in \mathbb N.$$

Comment: Hint: find $\theta_{j;n}$ for which $\sum_{j=0}^n\theta_{j;n}^{\,2}$ does not converge to zero, even though their maximum moduli converge to zero.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will try.
Is this true even with Gaussian innovations?

Comment: Because your question concerns only the first two moments of the innovations, whatever you demonstrate based on that information will be fully general and apply to any distribution satisfying the assumptions in (2).